# Is auto-logon on laptop with encrypted hard drive secure?

Tags: windows, security, encryption, disk-encryption, bitlocker

I have the complete hdd of my laptop encrypted (with the Windows built-in Bitlocker) and thus have to login two times upon booting (Bitlocker and user account).

Since I'm the only person using the computer (and knowing the Bitlocker password), I was thinking about automatically login into the user account to make the boot process smoother and quicker. In which cases/scenarios is this a bad idea and the additional login gives a true additionally layer of security?

Comment: auto-logon by itself is not secure.  The fact you have an encrypted drive which I assume is auto-mounted when you log into your user, means anyone with physical access to your computer can access your data.

Answer (score 1):

Local Windows accounts have never really been that secure in the first place. If someone is physically at your PC and is determined to nab your data, the Windows password is going to be the easiest step in that process to complete.

Windows password = deterrent for the average user.

I dont consider it a true additional layer of security in most scenarios.

All that being said, the choice is up to you, but youre better off thinking of the windows password as a deterrent than another true layer of security. IMO.